# When saving a customer in production, where to locate Stripe's source token

Tags: stripe-payments

I am following Stripe's account here: https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards

in particular where the customer information is saved:

```
(async function() {
  // Create a Customer:
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
    source: 'tok_mastercard',
    email: 'paying.user@example.com',
  });

  // Charge the Customer instead of the card:
  const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 1000,
    currency: 'usd',
    customer: customer.id,
  });

  // YOUR CODE: Save the customer ID and other info in a database for later.

})();
```

in development I can input `source: 'tok_mastercard'` and it operates as intended, however what would the token be in production when using `sk_live_...` ? the doc is not clear so far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The token would be something you create client-side when you collect the card details securely either using [Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js#elements)  or [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout). Those let you exchange card details for a Stripe Token with a unique id `tok_12345` that you then send to your server to create the customer and the charge.